# VBA Link Cell Fill colour between worksheets and apply conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to link the cell fill color from another worksheet to a Dashboard worksheet.
The idea being that when the user worksheet cell is green, green will show on the corresponding dashboard cell.

```
Sub AutolinkDashboard()

'Assign cell fill colour from selected worksheet to the Dashboard
   Sheets("Dashboard").Range("J2").Interior.Color = Sheets("ES").Range("T4").Interior.Color
   Sheets("Dashboard").Range("K2").Interior.Color = Sheets("ES").Range("M16").Interior.Color

End sub
```

I am trying to develop this as a macro, but when the cell color goes to, red for example, the dashboard cell color remains green.
The plan is for the dashboard cells then to be assigned a numerical value based on current conditional formatting (i.e 1 = up arrow, 0 = down arrow)

Comment: How are you triggering the macro? If you want it to run every time the colour changes, you may need to try putting the code within the Microsoft Excel Objects rather than the module, and use `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub`

Comment: Hello. Yes, the idea is for it to run when the source color updates. Could you please explain how I can use the Objects instead of a Module?

Comment: If you want to read the color of a fill which is applied as a result of Conditional Formatting, you need to use `DisplayFormat`.  So (eg) `Sheets("Dashboard").Range("J2").Interior.Color = Sheets("ES").Range("T4").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`